# Is there a graphical Virtual Joypad?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I searched anywhere and I could not find a Virtual Joypad for ROS.

What I'd like to do is something like the joypad in bottom right:

[image: image description]

before starting to write my own plugin for rqt/rviz I would like to know if I'm not going to do something that exists.

Thank you
Walter

PS You can download the GUI of the image here: https://github.com/officinerobotiche/simple_unav_console/
I created it to drive a robot directly connected by Serial to a uNav motor control board.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209325/is-there-a-graphical-virtual-joypad?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-16**:
+1. As @gvdhoorn mentioned, adding a feature to `rqt_robot_steering` is favourable idea. I also wanted the "DJ" pad like the image you posted for operating an omni-directional base but ended up using joy stick ([PR](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_joy/pull/6) is still open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rqt_robot_steering](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_robot_steering) plugin is similar to what you describe/show, but doesn't have the circular dpad. It also publishes `Twist` messages, so rate of turn and linear velocity are proportional to how much the scroll bars are turned up or down. From your image I gather that the dpad is on/off only, and that velocities are set using the sliders on the left.

The [ROS Android Teleop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.rosjava.android_apps.teleop) app does have a circular dpad, which could make control of a differential drive robot easier than the sliders of `rqt_robot_steering`. It also includes a simple `image_view` like component for streaming video.

> before starting to write my own plugin for rqt/rviz I would like to know if I'm not going to do something that exists.

Well, there are at least the above two.

Perhaps updating / extending `rqt_robot_steering` with a dpad control would be nice.

In any case I'd go for an rqt plugin.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-05-16**:
My circular pad is proportional. Vertical axis controls the forward speed, while horizontal axis controls the rotation speed. The sliders on the left only set the range of the speeds of the robot.
When you push the pad on the top it sends to the robot the max forward speed set by the slider.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-05-16**:
There's also the Teleop panel in rviz. It's in Panels->Add New Panel->rviz_plugin_tutorials->Teleop. Not quite the same as the d-pad interface, but it works.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2015-05-16**:
I tried it... non really usable ☺
It could be good if the max speeds were configurable

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was playing with QML and ROS recently and wrote [ros_qml](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml) package. So here is a quick [example](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml/blob/master/examples/joypad.qml) mimicking your interface (I was unsure about artwork licence, so drew my own). You can easily extend it with all these maximum speeds etc.

To run example:

```
roslaunch ros_qml ros_qml.launch qml_url:=`rospack find ros_qml`/examples/joypad.qml
```

The sliders control axes scaling factors from 0.0 to 1.0. A `geometry_msgs/Twist` message is published while the thumb position changes. Once the mouse button released the thumb goes back to center.

[image: image description]

Hope it helps.

P.S. The package depends on Qt 5.4, PyQt 5.4 (you may need to compile it for Python 2.7) and [rospy_message_converter](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_message_converter)

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2